# Prove $a^2<b^2\Longrightarrow -b<a<b$ where $0<b\in \mathbb{F}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, inequality, field-theory

Prove $a^2<b^2\Longrightarrow -b<a<b$ where $0<b\in \mathbb{F}$
$\mathbb{F}$ is the ordered field

I've tried going backwards with $\iff$s, though not quite there:
$\eqalign{-b<a<b & \iff 0<a+b<2b \\ &\iff 0<a^2+2ab+b^2<2b(a+b) \\ &\iff  0<a^2+2ab+b^2<2ab+2b^2 \\ &\iff -2ab<a^2+b^2<2b^2 \\ &\iff -2ab-b^2<a^2<b^2}$

If something like this can work, which condition should $-2ab-b^2$ serve? If not, how would you prove it otherwise? (Without using the completeness axiom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a^2<b^2$ is equivalent to $(b-a)(b+a)=b^2-a^2>0$.

From here, either $b-a>0$ and $b+a>0$ or $b-a<0$ and $b+a<0$. 
In the latter case we get $b<-a<-b<0$, which contradicts the assumption on $b$.

Therefore, $b-a>0$ and $b+a>0$. In other words, $a<b$ and $-b<a$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a \leq 0$

$(a^2<b^2=(-b)^2)\Longrightarrow a>-b$ because $x\mapsto x^2$ is decreasing on $\mathbb{R}_-$ and both $a$ and $-b$ are negative

We then have $-b<a\leq 0<b$

If $a \geq 0$
$a^2<b^2\Longrightarrow a<b$ because $x\mapsto x^2$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}_+$ and both $a$ and $-b$ are positive

We then have $-b\leq 0\leq a<b$